# How to check if there are two identical strings in a list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I'm making a game of hangman. I use a list to keep track of the word that you are guessing for, and a list of blanks that you fill in. But I can't figure out what to do if for example someone's word was `apple`, and I guessed `p`.

My immediate thought was to just find if a letter is in the word twice, then figure out where it is, and when they guess that letter put it in both the first and second  spot where that letter is. But I can't find

1. How to test if two STRINGS are duplicates in a list, and
2. If I were to use `list.index` to test where the duplicate letters are how to I find both positions instead of just one.

Comment: My answer, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to go through the list one by one and check if something comes up twice.

```
def isDuplicate(myList):
    a = []
    index = 0
    for item in myList:
        if type(item) == str:
            if item in a:
                return index
            else:
                a.append(item)
        index += 1
    return False
```

This function goes through the list and adds what it has seen so far into another list. Each time it also checks if the item it is looking at is already in that list, meaning it has already been seen before. If it gets through the whole list without any duplicates, it returns `False`.

It also keeps track of the index it is on, so it can return that index if it does find a duplicate.

---

Alternately, If you want to find multiple occurrences of a **given** string, you would use the same structure with some modifications.

```
def isDuplicate(myList, query):
    index = 0
    foundIndexes = []
    for item in myList:
        if item == query:
            foundIndexes.append(index)
        index += 1
    return foundIndexes
```

This would return a list of the indexes of **all** instances of `query` in `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a string for your word
2. Create a string for user input
3. Cut your string into letters and keep it on a list/array
4. Get input
5. Cut input into letters and keep it on another array
6. Create a string = "--------" as displayed message
7. Using a for loop check every position in both array lists and compare them
8. If yourArray[i] == inputArray[i]
9. Then change displayedString[i] = inputArray[i] and display message then get another input
10. If it doesnt match leave "-" sings
11. Displayed the "---a--b" string